# Como mudar um atributo de GLOBAL para WEBSITE

Tags: php, magento

Alguém sabe se é possível mudar um atributo de GLOBAL para WEBSITE? No meu caso em específico gostaria de mudar o atributo "Preço". Estou dizendo "atributo" mas na verdade não se se é esse o nome correto.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja possível apenas por banco.

Seria na tabela **catalog_eav_attribute** mas não sei como funciona o relacionamento dela com a **eav_attribute**.

Acredito que a coluna `attribute_id` da `eav_attribute` que contém o price, é o mesmo da coluna `attribute_id` da `catalog_eav_attribute` que contem Global, Website etc.

Exemplo:

Se o **attribute_id** do price na tabela **eav_attribute** seja **75**, o registro da tabela **catalog_eav_attribute** que você precisaria alterar seria o de **attribute_id = 75**.